# Fabric use a host config file

Tags: python, invoke, fabric

After a lot of reading I still don't understand how this really works. For example If I have a hosts.yml configuration file like this:

hosts.yml:

```
server1:
  host: serverip
  user: username
```

How should I use this to create a Connection? I had to rename the hosts.yml to fabric.yml to get access these data, through the context variable, e.g:

```
@task
def do(ctx):
    ctx['server1']
```

And it will give back a DataProxy, that I can't use for create connection, or I just didn't find in the documentation

My another problem: how is it possible to specify these hosts declared in the hosts.yml file with -H toggle? It only works if I create an alias in the *~/.ssh/config* file which is not so great at all.

Comment: Do you stil have the problem? I can post an answer tonight!

Comment: yes please do :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will answer you both questions by giving an example where you read an external file(.env file) which store information about the host you are trying to connect to with a specific user.

`info.env` content:

```
# The hostname of the server you want to connect to 
DP_HOST=myserverAlias

# Username you use to connect to the remote server. It must be an existing user
DP_USER=bence
```

`~/.ssh/config` contnet:

```
Host myserverAlias //it must be identical to the value of DP_HOST in info.env
     Hostname THE_HOSTNAME_OR_THE_IP_ADDRESS
     User bence //it must be identical to the value of DP_USER in info.env
     Port 22
```

Now in you `fabfile.py` you should do the following

```
from pathlib import Path
from fabric import Connection as connection, task
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import logging as logger
from paramiko import AuthenticationException, SSHException


@task
def deploy(ctx, env=None):
    logger.basicConfig(level=logger.INFO)
    logger.basicConfig(format='%(name)s ----------------------------------- %(message)s')

    if env is None:
        logger.error("Env variable and branch name are required!, try to call it as follows : ")
        exit()
    # Load the env files
    if os.path.exists(env):
        load_dotenv(dotenv_path=env, verbose=True)
        logger.info("The ENV file is successfully loaded")
    else:
        logger.error("The ENV is not found")
        exit()
    user = os.getenv("DP_USER")
    host = os.getenv("DP_HOST")
    try:
        with connection(host=host, user=user,) as c:
            c.run('whoami')
            c.run('mkdir new_dir')
    except AuthenticationException as message:
        print(message)
    except SSHException as message:
        print(message)
```

Then you can call you `fabfile.py` using the following command:

```
fab deploy -e info.env
```

Make sure your `info.env` resides in the same directory as your `fabfile.py`